# Swift: Result of pickerView has different optionality than expected by protocol uipickerviewdelegate

Tags: swift

I'm getting a warning regarding optionality:

> Result of pickerView has different optionality than expected by
>   protocol uipickerviewdelegate.

It seems the protocol want me to return an implicitly unwrapped optional String, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
import UIKit

class TimerViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate  {
  @IBOutlet var timerPickerView: UIPickerView!

  let timerPickerData = [Array(1...24), Array(1...60), Array(1...60)]

  ...

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return String(timerPickerData[component][row])
  }

}
```

Comment: +1 for getting SO with such a irritatingly crazy message "different optionality than expected by protocol".. who speaks like that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Swift signature for that delegate method:

```
optional public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
```

You can see at the end of it that it's supposed to be returning an optional string (`String?`), not an implicitly unwrapped optional string (`String!`) like you have. So the reason for the warning is because the method signatures differ between the protocol and your implementation, specifically that you changed the optionality from a regular optional to an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: What happens if you ignore the warning? Does it crash at runtime?